# How do I center a table in a container? (inline) HTML

Tags: html, html-table, resize, alignment, center

I have a table in my container (960px), I want to center it but it doesn't seem to work. My code is below;

```
<table align="center;">

<tr><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/volkracing.png" title=""   width="100%"></tr>

<tr> 
<td><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/ze40.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultratrack.jpg" title="">  </td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultra.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultral.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g27.jpg" title=""></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried various aligning methods, none of them seem to work. Also, the table isn't resizing for mobile devices now? But if I remove the Table Rows then it works. Any ideas?

Comment: try to put your table inside <center> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <center> <table align="center;">

<tr><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/volkracing.png" title=""   width="100%"></tr>

<tr> 
<td><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/ze40.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultratrack.jpg" title="">  </td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultra.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultral.jpg" title=""></td>

<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g27.jpg" title=""></td>
</tr>
</table></center>
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to resize the table for mobile sites?